# Swig-Doxygen translation lines still appear on C++ script

Tags: python, c++, doxygen, swig, documentation-generation

I am using swig to generate wrapper Python function for C++ based application. when using swig, I am using -doxygen option to translate doxygen document to python wrapper file. Inside C++ header file, I have following docstring. (I used this [link](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/Doxygen.html#Doxygen))

```
%module doxygen_ignore
%feature("autodoc", "1");

%feature("doxygen:ignore:transferfull");
%feature("doxygen:ignore:compileroptions", range="line");
%feature("doxygen:ignore:forcpponly", range="end");
%feature("doxygen:ignore:beginPythonOnly", range="end:endPythonOnly", contents="parse");


/**
    \ingroup A
    comment

    @forcpponly
    \code{.cpp}
    
    //c++ code

    \endcode
    @endforcpponly

    @beginPythonOnly
    \code{.py}

    //python code

    \endcode
    @endPythonOnly

*/
void function{};
```

After running swig, python wrapper file grabs right portion of comment (@beignPythonOnly to @endPythonOnly). Yet when I run doxygen on .i file essentially including this comment, not only cpp portion shows up but also python portion shows up as well on the html file produced.

[image]

What should I do to remove python portion in html that is doxygen-generated from cpp file?

Attempt #1

I tried if-else loop that would ignore python portion when swig is not running but it still did not work

```
#ifdef SWIGPYTHON
%feature("doxygen:ignore:transferfull");
%feature("doxygen:ignore:compileroptions", range="line");
%feature("doxygen:ignore:forcpponly", range="end");
%feature("doxygen:ignore:beginPythonOnly", range="end:endPythonOnly", contents="parse");
#elif doxygen
%feature("doxygen:ignore:forcpponly", range="end", contents="parse");
%feature("doxygen:ignore:beginPythonOnly", range="end:endPythonOnly");
#endif
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? It is a bit unclear what is in your doxygen settings file, but doxygen does not understand the commands like `@beginPythonOnly` and will issue a warning (like `warning: Found unknown command '@beginPythonOnly'`) and include the command name in the output (strange that you use a `@` in your code and in the output is a `\`). I think you should have a look at the `ALIASES` settings (and define e.g. `ALIASES += beginPythonOnly=`. Note also an interesting command for you might be `\noop`.

Comment: @albert Thanks for the help! I fixed it by using ALIASES.